Is it a bad idea to apply 12V to a NiMH 4S1P battery to revive it?
I have a stock of batteries with 4 NiMH cells in series. The issue is that many of them are at 2.4V, which is a very low voltage (0.6V per cell). I’ve seen articles suggesting that applying overvoltage or short-circuiting the battery can revive the cells, allowing them to charge again and provide enough autonomy for your equipment. My cells are 2700mAh, and my equipment requires 300mA.
I’ve seen that indeed, by applying 12V with a current limit of 1A for 10 seconds, the voltage increases, and the charger recognizes them. As a result, they charge properly.
But is this correct? Am I not damaging the cells by applying overvoltage? If I have a stock of good batteries and apply this, am I damaging them, and could they fail later when used in the equipment?
I ask this because, after reading other forums like Battery University, what they recommend are different charging profiles or cycles. They don't mention applying this "trick." I've only seen it in internet videos.
The issue is that doing charging cycles takes a lot of time. And this test takes at most 10 seconds, which would be ideal for handling large batches.
(Also the cells can be pretty old. Around 1 year in a warehouse without any charge cycle. And from datasheet they have a self discharge rate of 40% per month...)

It’s only a bad idea if they explode! Supposedly the cells can get  ‘needles’ forming internally. Hitting the cells with a burst of current vapourises these needles thus restoring battery function.  If the batteries are functioning normal, there should be no need to ‘revive’ them. If they have failed, and zapping them brings them back to life, then the issue of possible damage is moot - dead battery or a zapped dead battery fails is the same outcome.

"I've only seen it in internet videos" is probably enough to answer your question.

Yeah, you’re right, the smartest thing is to go to official sources. I imagine that the best thing will be to set the power supply to 6V (1.5V/cell) with a limit of 1 A, and leave it like that for 30 seconds to break those little dentrites. Then, put them in the charger; if it detects them well, great; if not, discard the battery. Ideally, it would be good to do cycles, but it’s such a large batch that it’s not feasible due to time and available instrumentation. The only thing that fits is a quick recovery test. And pray that a sufficient percentage recovers
